# npm run build. Как правильно?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Есть проект create-react-build. После сборки webpack добавляет к src всех файлов стилей, js  лишний слеш вначале (см. картинка). Когда я убираю этот слеш, приложение отображается корректно.
Но не могу понять где может быть ошибка. Не охота вручную всегда их убирать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ты посмотришь на это с другой стороны, если вместо того что бы открыть html как файл в браузере, открыть его на реальном веб-сервере

Comment: @dev_null, на само деле, сайт тоже не обязан в корне находиться - может быть какой-то раздел сайта. Тут надо понимать, как и где оно будет разворачиваться.

Comment: @Qwertiy обычно в этом разделе, и хранятся все ассеты. Прим. yii2

Comment: Но вообще согласен, открывать сайт как файл - так себе идея.

Comment: @dev_null, ну тут варианты есть. Вполне может быть желание при разворачивании на `smth.com/some-app` держать его статику внутри `/some-app/static`, а не мешать статику с десятка приложений в общий `/static`. Впрочем, тут опять нюанс, а может ли что-то вложенное открываться - относительный путь может и не быть решением.

Answer (score 0):

create-react-build дает возмозможность развернуть локальный сервер. 
жмешь npm start и открываешь в адресной строке http://localhost:3000 
там и будет твой проект со всеми зависимостями, если необходимо на локальном изменить, то надо смотреть webpack.config.js